# Set UniqueId of SPListItem

Tags: 2013, ssom

How to set `UniqueId` property of `SPListItem` programmatically using SSOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not recommended but there are certain scenarios which justify the use such as migration.

In the solution bellow I am seting `UniqueId` to be equal to `C483CED9-9546-46B0-BC84-C077658A9899`.

```
using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://sp2/sites/test"))
{
    using (SPWeb site = siteCol.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = site.Lists["unique"];

        SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
        item["Title"] = "Some item 5";
        MethodInfo dynMethod = item.GetType().GetMethod("UpdateInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
            new[] { typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(Guid), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool), typeof(bool) }, null);

        dynMethod.Invoke(item, new object[] { false, false, new Guid("{C483CED9-9546-46B0-BC84-C077658A9899}"), true, false, false, false, false, false, false });

        var items = list.GetItems();
    }
}
```